# No route matches [POST] "/manager"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am having an error with my first app in Rails and hoping somebody could help and give me some clues what to do with this.

Error:

> No route matches [POST] "/manager"

When I submit this form:

## Sign in

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: manager_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

My `route.rb` file is:

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      resources :users
      resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
      root 'static_pages#home'
      match '/manager', to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'get'
      match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',            via: 'get'
      match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',        via: 'delete'
end
```

My `session_controller.rb` is:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(name: params[:session][:name])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
      # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      redirect 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
  end
end
```

Ruby version: 2.1.5, Rails v. 4.2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/manager', to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'get'
  match '/manager', to: 'sessions#create',         via: 'post'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',        via: 'delete'
end
```

Now method will be available for /manager with post which will go to sessions controller create method

Check this route

`match '/manager', to: 'sessions#create',         via: 'post'`

This method says . Route name is `/managers` controller is `sessions` from `sessions#create` and `create` is method of controller sessions from `sessions#create` .

Answer (score 1):

Change to `POST` method

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/manager', to: 'static_pages#manager',    via: 'post'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',        via: 'delete'
end
```

Add `manager` method to `StaticPagesController`

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def manager
     # Create logic goes here 
  end

end
```